# How to read only last buffer from telnetlib command

Tags: python, telnetlib

I have following python code:

```
import telnetlib
ts = telnetlib.Telnet('192.168.0.2')
ts.set_debuglevel(10)
ts.read_until("assword:", 5)
ts.write("xxxxx\n")
ts.write("enable\n")
ts.read_until("assword:", 5)
ts.write("xxxxx\n")
ts.write("term len 0\n")
ts.write("show start\n")
```

But how can i read the buffer only from "show start" command?
If i try to read_(very)eager or read_all() I get all previous output too.
Im confused because it looks like i should parse string on my own wrrr :(
Maybe im wrong?

Comment: Please clarify your question.

what do you mean by "the buffer only from `show start`"? you sent that bit of string.

In any case, I don't know of a way to make telnetLib flush its buffers without returning them to you

Comment: In this case can't you just `read_all()` and strip off the first five or so lines?

Answer (score 4):

Try using `ts.read_until("")` before the command whose output you want to grab

```
import telnetlib  
ts = telnetlib.Telnet('192.168.0.2')  
ts.set_debuglevel(10) 
ts.read_until("assword:", 5)  
ts.write("xxxxx\n")  
ts.write("enable\n")  
ts.read_until("assword:", 5)  
ts.write("xxxxx\n")   
ts.read_until("")  #Add this line  
ts.write("term len 0\n")   
ts.write("show start\n")`
```